# conditions to check if Aerospike cluster is being idle

Tags: linux, aerospike, sre, aerospike-ce

Assuming aerospike is running, I need some conditions through which check weather aerospike cluster is idle and not being used at all.

I tried checking log files but it also logs the heartbeat, so even ifaerospike is not running it will generate logs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could monitor the histograms of each namespace on each node that is configured on the cluster in the log file. The log output has the following format: `histogram dump: {ns-name}-{hist-name} (1344911766 total) msec (00: 1262539302) (01: 0049561831) (02: 0013431778) (03: 0007273116) (04: 0004299011) (05: 0003086466) (06: 0002182478) (07: 0001854797) (08: 0000312272) (09: 0000370715)`  The ***total value*** is accumulated since the node is started. By tracking change in total count for each histogram (e.g. read, write etc.) - depending on your application, number of cluster nodes, and namespaces configured, you can infer if the cluster is being used or not.

Comment: Only edge this wouldn't catch is somehow if the transactions were failing (they would then not make the histograms). But then one could argue that the cluster is kind of idle if there are no successful transactions being processed at all ;)